# SWIG : unrecognized template type contained in vector

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, swig

I can't manage to have a valid SWIG output from a definition like this :

```
std::vector< namespaceA::refPtr< namespaceB::myObj > >
```

First of all, I have a custom definition of std::vector

```
namespace std {

template<class T> class vector {
  public:
    typedef size_t size_type;
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef value_type const& const_reference;
    /*
    ....
    */
    %rename(add) push_back;
    void push_back( const_reference x);
    %extend {
        const_reference get(int i) {
            int size = int(self->size());
            if (i>=0 && i<size)
                return (*self)[i];
            else
                return *((T*)NULL);
        }
        void set(int i, const_reference val) {
            int size = int(self->size());
            if (i>=0 && i<size)
                (*self)[i] = val;
        }
    }
};
}
```

In the namespace A, there is a template to reference pointers. Let's call it `refPtr`.
In the namespace B, there is a ref counted class, called `MyObj`.

When I declare a template for a ref counted object, SWIG outputs the correct interface :

```
%template(MyObjRefPtr) namespaceA::refPtr< namespaceB::MyObj > // OK
```

Then I declare my vector :

```
%template(MyObjRefPtrVector) std::vector< MyObjRefPtr > > // compiles but inner types not resolved
```

It compiles and SWIG generates four types :

- SWIGTYPE_p_std_*vectorTnamespaceA*_refPtrTnamespaceB__MyObj_t_t
- SWIGTYPE_p_MyObjRefPtr
- MyObjRefPtr
- MyObjRefPtrVector

The generated class `MyObjRefPtr` is ok.
The class `MyObjRefPtrVector` was generated but the methods `add`, `set` and `get` take a `SWIGTYPE_p_MyObjRefPtr` as parameter, instead of `MyObjRefPtr`.

Could someone show me where my code is wrong ? I just can't figure it out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
%template(MyObjRefPtrVector) std::vector< MyObjRefPtr > >
```

the template declaration should be

```
%template(MyObjRefPtrVector) std::vector< namespaceA::refPtr< namespaceB::MyObj > >
```